# 2x oversampling channelizers and perfect reconstruction

Tags: filters, filter-bank, polyphase

For perfect reconstruction, it seems that $2\times$ oversampling allows a prototype filter that ensure the spectrums of the subchannels overlap correctly.

In the gnuradio reference on this it seems the output after reconstruction is at $2f_s$, which makes sense as the oversampling process has twice the data.

So the question is, for perfect reconstruction, how can the output be at $f_s$ rather than $2f_s$? Is there some way, other than decimating, to have an $2\times$ oversampled channel synthesizer give output at $f_s$?

Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2x oversampling uses the windowed-sinc method (I might recommend a Kaiser window and perhaps 32 or 64 samples involved in the mid-sample interpolation), then you only have to calculate the mid-samples.  Half of your output samples will just be copying over the input sample at 1x to the output sample at 2x.  Then, if that is the way the original was upsampled, pure decimation (just tossing out the mid-samples that you fill in-between the originals) will be perfect down sampling.